# Read/Write/Save MS Word Document in c#

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

I have to open a word document using c# and do some changes in that document and save it again. Document will have lot of tables and styling. For example I have to process that document page by page. I have to change all italics to normal and all caps to small letters and save to that document only the changes without affecting the styling and alignment or format of the document.

Is that possible in c# .net? Please let me know it there any tutorial available based on my requirement. Basically I am a Java developer recently moved to c#. I have googled for past 2 days, I didn't get any proper data.

Comment: There is an Office library in the .NET framework. Here is a decent starting point. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264733.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I  use Aspose.NET. But that component is not free. If you need something free, I can also recommend the Microsoft Open XML Library:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/04/22/using-the-open-xml-sdk.aspx

I would not use Office Interop as Jim suggested. It's not very stable for server.